# Change timepicker value on option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have 2 options in my page:

If I click Option1 : timepicker should not be shown.

If I click Option2 : timepicker should be shown and minutes value should be rounded up to the nearest quarter;

Now while testing, before adding options, I have added this code to initialize my timePicker in $(document).ready event:

```
$('#pushTime').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {                         
  // update spanTime with current value
});
```

This code is getting the nearest rounded up hour quarter; I need to do this not in document.ready, but on option change because I want to get the last updated date from the system; Users could open my page since 30 mins and if I am relying on initializing timepicker only when page is opened then date won't be updated; So How can I make it when user clicks on Option2?

Below is my function:

```
function CheckScheduleRadioButton(elem) { 

   $(elem).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
   if ($(elem).find('input:radio').prop('value') == "option2") {   
      // initialize timepicker here
   }    
}
```

I have tried to initialize time picker in this function but it didn't work;
I have also tried this:

```
var currentTime = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
 $('#pushTime').timepicker({
                    'step': 15
 }).val(currentTime);
```

It is updating timePicker but with the exact value and not rounded to the next quarter;

example 8:13 won't change to 8:15

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the exact idea of how you are implementing the functionality. But just going through the above description, I get the basic idea to check that if radio button with value "Option 2" is checked, then the time picker should be initialized.

You can do this as:

```
function CheckScheduleRadioButton(elem) {
  if ($(elem).find('input:radio[value="Option 2"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
  }
}
```